# Facebook GET request - Should contain “fields” parameter for /me/friends

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, swift2

```
  func getFbFriendsAndSendToServer() {
        let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/friends", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]);
        request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

            //Save friends ID
            let fbFriendsData : NSArray = result["data"] as! NSArray
            for fbData in fbFriendsData {
                self.friendsFbIDs.addObject(fbData["id"] as! String);
            }

            //send friends FB IDs to remote server
            self.sendFriendsIDsOnServer()
        }
        else {
            self.showAlertViewWithRetryButton("PullCar", message: "Unable to get your Facebook friends. Please check your internet connection and try again.", tag: 102)
        }
    }
}
```

This Piece of code will not give me error as below.

> -[ Facebook Graph API GET request - Should contain “fields” parameter ]

Comment: Try to use  let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name, email"])

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? Does it reproduce with the latest one (v4.7.1 as of now) as well?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser Yes i'm Using  these Pods. If you still there is problem please let me know.
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.7'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.7'